# Javascript slideshow. Src of images in another directory

Tags: javascript, html, directory, slideshow, src

I'm new in Java script and I'm trying to build a slideshow for my page.
Here is my html code:

```
<div id="sildeshow">    
        <img src="Imagini\CEJ2016\img3.jpg" id="imag">
        <div id="stanga"><img onclick='slideSHOW(-1)' class="buton_stanga" src="Imagini\left.png"></div>
    <div id="dreapta"><img onclick='slideSHOW(1)' class="buton_dreapta" src="Imagini\right.png"></div>
</div>
```

and my Js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numar_imagine=1;
    var maxim=14;

    function slideSHOW(x){
        var imagine=document.getElementById('imag');
        numar_imagine +=x;
        if(numar_imagine>maxim){
            numar_imagine=1;
        }
        if(numar_imagine<0){
            numar_imagine=maxim;
        }
        imagine.src="Imagini\CEJ2016\img" + numar_imagine + ".jpg";
    }
</script>
```

Now, the thing is that for some reason my img source does not change properly when I press my left/right arrows.

Trying to solve the problem I noticed that if my images are in same directory with my .html file the code works.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Please share a jsFiddle URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\ is escape char.
your solution is below

```
function slideSHOW(x){
    var imagine=document.getElementById('imag');
    numar_imagine +=x;
    if(numar_imagine>maxim){
        numar_imagine=1;
    }
    if(numar_imagine<0){
        numar_imagine=maxim;
    }
   imagine.src="Imagini\\CEJ2016\\img" + numar_imagine + ".jpg";
}
```

Comment: Ahh you beat me too it

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash in your string for your source in your JavaScript

`imagine.src="Imagini\\CEJ2016\\img" + numar_imagine + ".jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
imagine.src="Imagini\\CEJ2016\\img" + numar_imagine + ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `\` instead of `/` in the first place?

this solves the problem:

```
imagine.src="Imagini/CEJ2016/img" + numar_imagine + ".jpg";
```

Or maybe try adding extra escape `\` as other answers says.

Comment: A realistic solution!